# Search User Playlists by Followers?

Tags: spotify

Is there anyway, using the Spotify API, to rank user playlists by how many followers they have or some other criteria? As opposed to having to search for a certain user first

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Find the user-created playlist with the most followers, out of every user playlist on Spotify," the answer is "No, there is no way to do that with the Spotify API."